# SDL Lag / Super slow (SDL 2.0.14)

Tags: c++, window, sdl, lag

i have a game loop which measures the ms it takes to finish.
before entering the loop i call a "Init" function which looks like this:

```cpp
void screen::Init()
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
    {
        m_window = SDL_CreateWindow("TITLE", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WIDTH*SIZE, HEIGHT*SIZE, NULL);

        m_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_window, -1, NULL);
        if(m_renderer)
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_renderer, 0,0,0,0);

        m_Texture = SDL_CreateTexture(m_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    }
}
```

The thing is that when i call the function one execution of the loop takes 70 to 90 ms!
if i leave the "init" function call out (so no window shown) its only 2-4 ms.

The loop does nothing other than calling one function which looks like the following:

```cpp
void screen::handleEvents()
{
    SDL_PollEvent(&m_event);
    switch(m_event.type)
    {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            screen->Clean();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

leaving the handleEvents function out results in 0-2ms, but the window crashes the moment i click on it.

not sure what im doing wrong but im pretty sure it shouldnt slow down to ~10 FPS lol

Here is the rest of the code:

```cpp
#define SIZE 5
#define WIDTH 150
#define HEIGHT 150

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    screen* screen = new class screen;

    screen->Init();

    while(screen->running)
    {
        screen->execute();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
void screen::execute()
{
    if(currline == 1 && Time == 0)
        start = SDL_GetTicks();

    if(Time > 0)
        Time--;
    else
        counter();

    handleEvents();

    if(currline == 151 && Time == 0)
    {
        end = SDL_GetTicks();
        printf("s: %8d e: %8d r: %d\n", start, end, end-start);
    }
}
```

```cpp
void screen::counter()
{
    if(currline > 150)
        currline = 255;

    currline++;

    Time = 500;
};
```

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: If you are using msvc make sure you are running a release build. I have seen cases where the debug version took 100 times as long as the release version.

Comment: Isn't the Init being called 1 time? I don't think any of the code shown is helpful to determine a timing problem in that if there is a performance problem, I don't believe the shown code is the cause.

Comment: i tried both debug and release but the results are almost the same. release is 3-5 ms faster.

Comment: the loop increases one value and when it reaches a certain number its reset to 0, and it shows how long it took. this repeats pretty much the whole time

Comment: Sorry but this is niether minimal nor reproducible (or even compilable). What's your OS? What if you do `SDL_INIT_VIDEO` instead of everything? You only need to react on event if `SDL_PollEvent` returned non-zero.

Comment: Windows 10, SDL_INIT_VIDEO is just a little bit faster, doenst really change much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, found out why it was lagging:

i was calling handleevent everytime it executed a loop (which is a couple thousand times per second) instead of doing it inside this if statement:

```cpp
if(currline == 151 && Time == 0)
    {
        end = SDL_GetTicks();
        printf("s: %8d e: %8d r: %d\n", start, end, end-start);
    }
```

the if statement is there to "restrict" the whole thing to a certain framerate :)

usually you would do a sleep at the end of the whole loop to get your 60 executions per second, but since i did it inside this if statment i had to put the function-call in there.